# PHPSpreadsheet and writing large numbers of decimal places

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

I'm having difficulty with [PHPSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) when creating an XLSX file and attempting to write large numbers of decimal places to numerical values.

PHPSpreadsheet is rounding my 14 decimal place numbers, but I need them stored exactly as presented.

I'm using `setFormatCode('0.00000000000000')` as described in the [documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/#number-formats), but it's not working as I would expect.

Here's my test code:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; // Installed via composer

$spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();

$array = [
         0.03790728347833,
      1345.28748532874927,
    121345.18248762894914, // all 14 DP
];

$format = '0.00000000000000'; // 14 DP

// write the data
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->fromArray($array, null, 'A1');

// Format the cells
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:C1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode($format);

// Column sizing
foreach(range('A','C') as $columnID)
{
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setAutoSize(true);
}

$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save("test.xlsx");

// A1 = 0.03790728347833 - same
// A2 = 1345.28748532870000 - rounded
// A3 = 121345.18248763000000 - rounded
```

Could anyone provide a way to store this many decimal places without rounding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a limitation of Excel rather than PHPSpreadsheet.

Excel is limited to 15 significant figures [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel).