# PHPSpreadsheet not showing decimal numbers, despite using formatting

Tags: php, excel, symfony, phpspreadsheet

I'm working on an Excel export where each row needs to have a percentage value, rounded to one decimal place. After exporting the spreadsheet, users need to be able to use those values for calculations inside the spreadsheet, hence why I can't simply format them as strings (or percentages, Excel doesn't like calculations using percentages for some reason). I've tried a few different things, but none of them work;

```
$sheet->getCell($coord)->setValueExplicit(
    $amount['percentage'],
    DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC
);
```

in which `$coord` is the required cell (for example `'A1'`) and `$amount['percentage']` is a float like `45.2`.

Another thing I've tried (and got straight from the PHPSpreadsheet documentation);

```
$sheet->setCellValue($coord, $amount['percentage']);
$sheet->getStyle($coord)
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_00);
```

In both cases the number is added as a whole number without decimal places (so `45` instead of `45.2`), the decimal number only shows when clicking the "Increase Decimal" button in excel.

If I change `DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC` to `DataType::TYPE_STRING` the number is displayed the way I want, but since it's printed as a string it can't be used for further calculations.

Is it at all possible to always display the decimal number after exporting?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this?

```
$sheet->getStyle($coord)
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('0.000000');
```

[Excel supports a maximum 15 significant figures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52630134/2693543)

Comment: `NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_00`'s value is `'0.00'`, so pretty much the same as what you suggested which sadly doesn't work.

Comment: Well... I think you are better off with `FORMAT_NUMBER_00 ` even though excel shows only the significant figures, you can format the entire column and change the number format to show enough decimals. Here are some info, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680465/how-to-change-the-default-number-format-in-excel. You can google around to find a way to show the default number of decimal places in excel.